# How to pass `Option<&mut ...>` to multiple function calls without causing move errors?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Since it's possible to pass a mutable reference to a vector around (without causing moves), how can an `Option<reference>` be passed to functions multiple times without causing borrow checking errors?

This simple example just shows what happens when an `Option<&mut Vec<usize>>` is passed multiple times to a function:

```
fn maybe_push(mut v_option: Option<&mut Vec<usize>>) -> usize {
    let mut c = 0;
    if let Some(ref mut v) = v_option.as_mut() {
        for i in 0..10 {
            v.push(i);
            c += i;
        }
    }

    return c;
}

fn maybe_push_multi(v_option: Option<&mut Vec<usize>>) -> usize {
    let mut c = 0;
    c += maybe_push(v_option);
    c += maybe_push(v_option);
    c += maybe_push(None);
    return c;
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<usize> = vec![];
    let v_option = Some(&mut v);
    println!("{}", maybe_push_multi(v_option));
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9d06575206bb5dfe575db524747d68bd&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Gives the error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `v_option`
  --> <anon>:17:21
   |
16 |     c += maybe_push(v_option);
   |                     -------- value moved here
17 |     c += maybe_push(v_option);
   |                     ^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `v_option` has type `std::option::Option<&mut std::vec::Vec<usize>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the `Option` by reference too, if you don't want it moved into the function.

```
fn maybe_push(mut v_option: &mut Option<&mut Vec<usize>>) -> usize

// ...

maybe_push_twice(&mut v_option);
```

Then replace:

```
maybe_push(None);
```

With:

```
maybe_push(&mut None);
```

Comment: This is how I resolved it, but I admit it looks REALLY UGLY.

Comment: Update: The answer from @maoe using `.as_deref_mut()`  is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can destructure the `Option` with a `match` expression and then create a new `Option` value for every call of the function `maybe_push()`:

```
fn maybe_push_twice(v_option: Option<&mut Vec<usize>>) -> usize {
    let mut c = 0;
    match v_option {
        Some(v) => {
            c += maybe_push(Some(v));
            c += maybe_push(Some(v));
        }
        None => {
            c += maybe_push(None);
            c += maybe_push(None);        
        }
    };
    return c;
}
```

---

Here is a more convenient way:

```
fn maybe_push_twice(mut v_option: Option<&mut Vec<usize>>) -> usize {
    let mut c = 0;
    c += maybe_push(v_option.as_mut().map(|x| &mut **x));
    c += maybe_push(v_option);
    return c;
}
```

---

You can use a trait instead of a macro:

```
trait RefMut<T> {
    fn ref_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T>;
}

impl<'t, T> RefMut<T> for Option<&'t mut T>{
    #[inline]
    fn ref_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T>{
        self.as_mut().map(|x| &mut**x)
    }
}

fn maybe_push_twice(mut v_option: Option<&mut Vec<usize>>) -> usize {
    let mut c = 0;
    c += maybe_push(v_option.ref_mut());
    c += maybe_push(v_option);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Good to know as an alternative to the existing answer. While a valid, this makes it annoying to use when passing an argument to functions many times. I'd be tempted to put `opt.as_mut().map(|x| &mut **x)` into a macro.

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.40.0, you can use [Option::as_deref_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref_mut).

```rust
fn maybe_push_twice(mut v_option: Option<&mut Vec<usize>>) -> usize {
    let mut c = 0;
    c += maybe_push(v_option.as_deref_mut());
    c += maybe_push(v_option);
    c
}
```

Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=372c5713313a0b6049b3b0179b230995) modified from the original playground.