# Read reference from Option<&mut T> multiple times

Tags: rust

I have an `Option<&mut T>` and want to access the contained reference multiple times, like so:

```
fn f(a: Option<&mut i32>) {
    if let Some(x) = a {
        *x = 6;
    }
    // ...
    if let Some(x) = a {
        *x = 7;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;
    f(Some(&mut x));
}
```

That doesn't work, because `if let Some(x) = a` moves the reference value out of the Option, and the second `if let Some(x) = a` will result in a compiler error. Without the second `if let ...`, this works flawlessly, so `a` doesn't have to be mutable.

The following:

```
if let Some(ref x) = a {
    **x = 6;
}
```

gives an error: "assignment into an immutable reference".

This would work:

```
fn f(mut a: Option<&mut i32>) {
    if let Some(ref mut x) = a {
        **x = 6;
    }
    if let Some(ref mut x) = a {
        **x = 7;
    }
}
```

The `mut a` is necessary, otherwise I get an error "cannot borrow immutable anonymous field `(a:std::prelude::v1::Some).0` as mutable". But this feels wrong: `a` shouldn't have to be mutable, because I'm not modifying it (see above).

What's the correct solution?

#### Edit 1

My problem is different from the one in [How to pass `Option<&mut ...>` to multiple function calls without causing move errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658487/how-to-pass-optionmut-to-multiple-function-calls-without-causing-move-e). I want to mutably dereference the reference in an `Option<&mut T>` multiple times, while the other one wants to pass an `Option` to multiple function invocations. The solutions to the other question are not applicable to my situation.

Comment: The other answers are just fine. Really. Just take a mutable reference to your argument as the first thing if you need to.

Comment: You mean like this: `let tmp = &mut a; if let &mut Some(ref mut x) = tmp { ...`? But then `a` has to be `mut`, which is exactly what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: *But then `a` has to be `mut`*; yes, what's the problem with that? No one outside of your function cares (or *can* care) if that argument is `mut`. You own it so you can do whatever you want. You could also do `let mut tmp1 = a; let mut tmp2 = &mut tmp1;` if it really bothered you.

Comment: *"yes, what's the problem with that?"* I was looking for a solution that is better/cleaner/more elegant than the one I had already found (the one below "This would work").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
fn f(a: Option<&mut i32>) {
    if let Some(&mut ref mut x) = a {
        *x = 6;
    }
    // ...
    if let Some(&mut ref mut x) = a {
        *x = 7;
    }
}
```

In this case, `a` doesn't need to be mutable.

The `&mut ref mut` feels a bit awkward, but it makes sense: first we remove a `&mut` by destructuring and then take a mutable reference to the value again. It's more obvious when we don't use the `Option`:

```
let mr: &mut Vec<u32> = &mut vec![];
{
    let &mut ref mut a = mr;
    a.push(3);
}
mr.push(4);
```

This also works. The third (special) line is equivalent to:

```
let a = &mut     *mr   ;
//               ^^^----- this is an lvalue of type `Vec<u32>`
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^----- together it's of type `&mut Vec<u32>` again
```

In the `Option` case, we can't use the `&mut *X` version, but need to do all of it inside of the pattern. Thus the `&mut ref mut x`.

Comment: *It also kind of makes sense* => If it makes sense to you, I wouldn't mind an explanation ;) I know that `&mut T` is NOT Copy (unlike `&T`), but I don't see how this awkward dance helps bypass the move. Would there be some reborrowing?

Comment: The `&mut` in the let-pattern destructures the reference, and the following `ref mut x` creates a new reference to the i32-value. This is conceptually different from reading the `&mut i32`-reference, but should generate the same instructions.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I tried to explain it a bit more ^_^ I hope its clearer now.