# Destructuring a mutable peekable iterator

Tags: rust

I am trying to iterate over a mutable buffer of `&[u8]` and whenever there is a `--` delete all bytes until I encounter an `'\n'`

I tried this approach which gives an error that I cannot resolve

```
fn remove_comments_in_place<'a>(buffer: &'a mut [u8]) {
    #[derive(PartialEq)]
    enum Mode {
        COMMENT,
        CODE,
    }
    let mut mode = Mode::CODE;
    let mut iter = buffer.iter_mut().peekable();
    while let Some(ch) = iter.next() {
        match ch {
            // Look 2 chars ahead to identify comments
            &mut b'-' => {
                if let Some(&&mut ref mut hyphen) = iter.peek() {
                    if hyphen == &mut b'-' {
                        *hyphen = b' ';
                        *ch = b' ';
                        mode = Mode::COMMENT;
                    }
                }
            }
            &mut b'\r' => *ch = b' ',
            &mut b'\n' => {
                *ch = b' ';
                if mode == Mode::COMMENT {
                    mode = Mode::CODE;
                }
            }
            _ => if mode == Mode::COMMENT {
                *ch = b' '
            },
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error[E0389]: cannot borrow data mutably in a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:13:35
   |
13 |                 if let Some(&&mut ref mut hyphen) = iter.peek() {
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment into an immutable reference
```

I also tried changing the assignment to

```
&mut b'-' => {
    if let Some(&&mut hyphen) = iter.peek() {
        if hyphen == b'-' {
            hyphen = b' ';
            *ch = b' ';
            mode = Mode::COMMENT;
        }
    }
}
```

but received the following error:

```
warning: value assigned to `hyphen` is never read
  --> src/main.rs:15:25
   |
15 |                         hyphen = b' ';
   |                         ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_assignments)] on by default

error[E0384]: re-assignment of immutable variable `hyphen`
  --> src/main.rs:15:25
   |
13 |                 if let Some(&&mut hyphen) = iter.peek() {
   |                                   ------ first assignment to `hyphen`
14 |                     if hyphen == b'-' {
15 |                         hyphen = b' ';
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ re-assignment of immutable variable
```

[This question suggests my destructuring is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320750/read-reference-from-optionmut-t-multiple-times), so how do I assign into `hyphen` with my `Option<&mut T>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably go back and refresh yourself about [mutability with the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html). [`Peekable::peek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html#method.peek) returns an *immutable reference*:

```
impl<I> Peekable<I>
where
    I: Iterator, 
{
    fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<&<I as Iterator>::Item>
    //                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

As it is immutable you... cannot mutate it.

```
&mut b'-' => {
    if let Some(next) = iter.peek() {
        if b'-' == **next {
            *ch = b' ';
            mode = Mode::COMMENT;
        }
    }
}
```